# Pass curried kprintf as function argument

Tags: generics, f#, functional-programming, printf

I have a problem with passing *Printf* kind of functions as arguments.
Ultimate goal, is to create a custom logging function, that could be than injected into other methods that assume logging. So, I learned how to use *kprintf*. But how to pass its result up the callstack.
Could anybody please help me to make the following code working?

```
open System

type logging () =
    let logWarning =
        let logToConsole msg = Console.WriteLine("WARN: {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, msg)
        fun fmt -> Printf.kprintf logToConsole fmt

    let doThingsWithLogging warningLogger =
        warningLogger "%s %d %f" "DoThingsWithLogger" 3 3.29
        warningLogger "%d %A" 3 "DoThingsAgain"

    member __.RunTest() =
        logWarning "%s %d %f" "String, int, float" 12 38.8
        logWarning "%d %f %s" 83 128.9 "int, float, string"

        doThingsWithLogging logWarning

let test = logging()
test.RunTest ()
```

If you try to run it in FSI, you'll see immediately, where the problem is - type inferring on the *warningLogger* argument does not let to compile the second call to this function.
How can I make it working so, that I can use *warningLogger*, as normal *printf* type of function?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In general, F# does not let you pass generic functions as arguments. This is not that easy to see in your example (because format strings are more tricky), but you can see that in the following simpler case:

```
let foo f =  
  f 1
  f 1.0
```

There is no way to tell the compiler that the argument `f` should be a generic function `'a -> unit` and so this will not compile.

The easiest solution in your example is probably to define a type that has a generic `LogWraning` method and then pass around an instance of the type. Something like this:

```
type Logger() =
  member x.LogWarning fmt =
    let logMessage msg = Console.WriteLine("WARN: {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, msg)
    Printf.kprintf logMessage fmt

let doThingsWithLogging (logger:Logger) =
    logger.LogWarning "%s %d %f" "DoThingsWithLogger" 3 3.29
    logger.LogWarning "%d %A" 3 "DoThingsAgain"

doThingsWithLogging (Logger())
```